# Edit button tooltip color Prime React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, primereact

i'm trying to change the background color of a tooltip, i'm using prime react button (https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/tooltip).

[image: Tooltip image]

My code:

```
<DebtorClientColumn>
   <Tooltip tooltip="Mensagem do tooltip" tooltipOptions={{ position: "bottom" }}>
      <DebtorIcon
        data-testid={`debtor-icon-${client._id}`}
       />
   </Tooltip>
```

I've tryed to style the DebtorClientColumn and the Tooltip but both doesn't work:

```
const Tooltip = styled(Button)`
    .p-tooltip{
        background-color: ${Colors.white} !important;
        color:  ${Colors.white} !important;
    }   
    
    .p-tooltip-arrow     {
        background-color: ${Colors.white} !important;
        color:  ${Colors.white} !important;

    }
    
    .p-tooltip-text      {
        background-color: ${Colors.white} !important;
        color: ${Colors.strawberry} !important;

    }
`

const DebtorClientColumn = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    .p-button, .p-button:enabled:active, .p-button:enabled:hover{
        background-color: ${Colors.white};
        border: none;
        font-size: 0px
    };

    .p-button:enabled:focus {
        box-shadow: none
    };

    .p-tooltip{
        background-color: ${Colors.white} !important;
    }   
    
    .p-tooltip-arrow     {
        background-color: ${Colors.white} !important;
    }
    
    .p-tooltip-text      {
        background-color: ${Colors.white} !important;
        color: ${Colors.strawberry} !important;
    }
`
```

Comment: Bad tagging primefaces is JSF and has nothing to do with react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the styled component joining the Icon

Here you can see the column or the main component that should render your tooltip

```
const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;

    &:hover ${Tooltip} {
        display: inline;
        text-align:center
    }
  `
```

here the tooltip component:

```
const Tooltip = styled.div`
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 28px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 0 black;
    background-color: ${Colors.white};
    padding: 6px;
`;
```

you should handler the component using:

```
 <Container>
  <Tooltip />
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tooltipOptions` and provide a custom class.

[Working demo (hoverover on the button)](https://codesandbox.io/s/prime-react-tooltip-issue-fix-yn995?file=/src/demo/TooltipDemo.js)

**JSX**

```js
       <Button
          tooltipOptions={{
            className: "hoverClass",
            showDelay: 500,
            hideDelay: 101300
          }}
          type="button"
          label="Save"
          icon="pi pi-check"
          tooltip="Click to proceed"
        />
```

**CSS**

```js
.hoverClass .p-tooltip-text {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

**Edit:**

Tool tips are `portals`, they are a separate render tree. Styled component's classes are scoped to the element that has been styled. You can target styled elements and the elements inside it but when it comes to portals, you cannot apply classes. See [github issue here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2620).

So in your case, for styling tooltip use regular css as mentioned  in this answer.

Comment: just realised that you are uisng styled component... i will update my answer shortly.

Comment: hi, thanks for help but isnt working using a className

Comment: yes, it doesn't work if you provide the class name with styled components. Just for tooltip use the class name from regular css as mentioned in the answer